# Find ordinal of a strange ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I was asked the following question:

for every $x\in \mathbb R$ we define the set $Q(x)=\{q \in \mathbb Q|q\leq x\}$, the set of all rational numbers less or equal to $x$.

Let $M=\{Q(x)|x\in \mathbb R\}$ the set of such sets $Q$, $M$ is a subset of the power set of $\mathbb Q$.

1) is $M$ linearly ordered with the relation $\subseteq$?

2) Find the ordinal $[(M,\subseteq)]$

I managed to show that 1) is true,$\subseteq$ defines a linear order on $M$, but how do I find the ordinal? it's infinite, but it isn't anything related to $\omega$ because $\omega$ has a beginning, it has a smallest value. $M$ doesn't have minimal element with respect to $\subseteq$.

Comment: Not every order type is an ordinal: only the well-ordered ones are. Do you have reason to believe $(M, \subseteq)$ is well-ordered?

Comment: I don't think it is well-ordered. $M$ itself doesn't have a least element.

Comment: So the question is flawed? Not answerable?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me. If you were asked to find the "order type" it would make sense (there is a fairly simple ordered set that is isomorphic to $(M, \subseteq)$), but it's certainly not an ordinal.

Comment: What do the square brackets mean?

Comment: We refer to ordinals as equivalence classes. ok, in that case, what is the order type?

Comment: $M$ is bijective with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes I know, $(M,\subseteq)$ is order-isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,\leq)$ what I meant is, what is the notation for such order type? like (I know this is a bad example) $\omega$ is the notation for the ordinal on the natural numbers, what is the notation for this order type? if it even exists

Comment: According to [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderType.html), both $\theta$ and $\lambda$ have been used to denote the order type of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is the most common notation, particularly in the partition calculus.